# Page width is crazy wide...can't find the css that is causing it

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site at http://www.uniqueamb.biz/bl and the page widths are very wide.  I can't seem to find the offending code...

Comment: This isn't the place for "here's my site, what's wrong with it?". Did you try to do *any* debugging on your own?

Comment: No he's not, you have to scroll right.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it's too localized, and unlikely to help any future visitors.  The best questions have a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code directly into the question. Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 7):

`.header { width: 1100%; }` typo